# Is it possible to append html to a class or div using razor syntax

Tags: razor, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-views

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and have a question in regards to accesssing html classes or divs via razor syntax.

Is it possible to access a html class or div via razor syntax and append some html code to the class or div?

Is there a html helper that can do this, or is it possible to create a html helper than can do this?

I am wanting to add html code to certain class and div elements where I have the class and div name and the html code to add.

Thanks

Comment: Html helpers generate html, they do not access existing html. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Still not clear. You can easily create your own html helper methods that generate `<div>` elements with class names - e.g. [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955073/converting-asp-net-mvc-razor-helper-function-into-a-method-of-a-helper-class/26955246#26955246) which outputs a label, textbox and validation message for a property inside bootstrap styled div elements. You need to indicate what html you want to output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what I need, it is called Html Agility Pack.

I was looking for something to access html, and razor does not support this. Html Agility Pack can load an html document into memory and code can be written to access, add, delete and modify content.